# Replace a word in a string with another word or sentence

Tags: php, mysql

I imported products from my business software to my shop everything worked OK however it only imported part of the description when the description contained characters such as ® and other strange characters.

For example:

Data exported to Shop: X-Ring 10,82 x 1,78 mm BS013 Viton® 75 +/- 5 Shore A schwarz/black

Data imported into Shop: X-Ring 10,82 x 1,78 mm BS013 Viton

After the word Viton everything else was deleted I suppose the character ® was the problem because we are in Europe and the import program did not consider this.

My question is how can I search "Viton" and replace it with "Viton® 75 +/- 5 Shore A schwarz/black"

I cannot change the program nor am I a programmer however I do know how to do a few commands within mysql. I am looking for a command replace "&Viton&" command with "Viton® 75 +/- 5 Shore A schwarz/black"

Thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: `UPDATE your_table SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'Viton', 'Viton&#174;') WHERE your_field LIKE '%Viton%'` Where `&#174;` is the html entity for the symbol. Always backup your data before trying queries though!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we are a community for programming Q&A, not a self-help service to assist you modifying/fixing some 3rd party code/database. Please make sure to read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center, before asking.

Comment: @Sherif I tend to disagree a bit with you here. He's not asking us to help fix a 3rd party program or database. He's asking to help fix his own database and it's not like he was asking something that takes more than a min to answer. I agree he should still do his own research before asking, but in this case I don't think it's needed to be so strict about the guidelines.

Comment: Dear Sir or Madam,

I checked Google for an answer however all answers I found did not seem to fit my needs. I did however discover your Forum / Website through this search. 
I am sorry if I violated your forum rules however I thought if I could not find an answer that suits my needs then I can ask the forum. I am not a programmer
nor am I part of a programming company. I am a small company that has nothing to do with software or Hardware just trying to solve a problem myself.

Best regards

Arby

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the HTML entity `&reg;` or as icecub suggest`&#174;`  , which will display as the circled R on a web page. Anyway, search replace on a single column like this

Step 1. MAKE A BACKUP OF THE TABLE!

Step 2, execute this query.

```
update TABLE  
set `COLUMN` = 
replace(`COLUMN`, 'Viton', 'Viton&reg; 75 +/- 5 Shore A schwarz/black');
```